# Unable to use package manager console in visual studio 2019 that running inside Virtual Machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, aspnetboilerplate, package-managers, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to run my .NET Core 3.1 Applications by Windows Virtual Machine with new Visual studio 2019 IDE (my Applications not created in this Virtual Machine) but I encountered two problems first one is :
VS couldn't restore all solution packages , second one is : So when I wan't to try to solve this problem by some commands using Package Manager console I encountered below problem

**Unable to find fallback package folder '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'.**

And here is the screen shoot:
[image: l]

Note : My Application has been built by (Asp.net core Boilerplate framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, I followed below steps and everything worked fine:

1. first of all, you should edit the paths in **project. assets file** to become refers to a new project path.
2. Open Power Shell for the same directory that .sln file exist then run below command

   ```
   PS E:\WorkSpace\VMTEST\5.5.0\aspnet-core\src\VMTEST.Web.Core\obj>dotnet restore VMTEST.sln
   ```

   (if won't work, run the command again)
3. Ensure that you have cleared the Nuget caches.
4. clean your project.
5. Build your project.
6. close the VS and reopen it again.

In my case the above steps fix the problem (both problem Package console and restore packages problem).